# How to add Drupal Coupon discount for selected category or item only?

Tags: commerce

Project:    Commerce Coupon
Version:    7.x-1.0-beta7

Hi,

We are using drupal percentage coupon module for our websites and its very good.We have a request from customer where they need to exclude coupon discount for selected item/category.Reason they have a category which is having already discounted items.So now they need a feature where they can exclude coupon applying for those items.

Can we do this with existing module?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You you can do it by adding new [RULES](https://drupal.org/project/rules). If you are using Percentage Coupon then you must have a rule in the list of rules list named "Calculate coupon with percentage amount".

Clone this rule & add more conditions according to your need like "Order contains products of particular product types" or "Order contains a particular product".

Its totally upto you to use conditional based discount and disable the default coupon redeem rules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add a Reaction Rule for the "Validate a coupon" event.

Check the conditions there and fail validation if it doesn't match.

You can refer to the existing coupon validation rules there for reference.

Alternatively, you could take the approach RajeevK suggested and add the condition to the "Redeem a coupon" rule for the coupon instead.